# Is it safe to use the variable from dictionary comprehension during error handling?

Tags: python

Consider the following example:

```
config_parameters = ['PARAM1', 'PARAM2', 'PARAM3']
sample_config = {
    'PARAM1': 'Value1',
    'PARAM2': 'Value2'
}

try:
    # Collects param values from the sample config
    config = {k: sample_config[k] for k in config_parameters}
except KeyError as e:
    # Tries using comprehension var `k` to advise which variable was missing
    raise KeyError(f'Value: "{k}" missing from config file.')
```

In error handling, it tries to catch key errors that arise during a strict dict lookup step which using dict comprehension. For any caught errors, it attempts to utilize a variable that was assigned during the dict comprehension.

Is this considered safe with Python, or is there any reason to expect that `k` may not indicate the same value which caused the error?

Comment: Does `k` even exist outside of the context of the comprehension?

Comment: @JonSG Not in Python 3; that was an explicit change made to avoid leading comprehension variables from leaking into the current scope.

Comment: Your edit completely changes the question, as the code no longer even *attempts* to use `k`.

Comment: The last edit when run shows you *"NameError: name 'k' is not defined"*. See @chepner's answer that uses the walrus opperator `:=` to work around this.

Comment: Sorry. I used a NLM to quickly stepback and clean up my mess with a more minimal example. It introduced a mess of its own, I noticed.

Comment: `k` will not be visible in the exception clause. From [Displays for lists, sets and dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries): _[...] the comprehension is executed in a separate implicitly nested scope. This ensures that names assigned to in the target list don’t “leak” into the enclosing scope._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables defined in a comprehension are considered local to the comprehension, so `k` cannot be used outside of the `dict` display. (This was a change made in Python 3 to prevent such leakage.)

Assignment expressions were specifically defined to allow the "extraction" of a value from that anonymous namespace, however. (See https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#scope-of-the-target)

```
try:
    # Collects param values from env vars
    config = {k: sample_config[(offending_key := k)] for k in config_parameters}
except KeyError:
    raise KeyError(f'Value: "{offending_key}" missing from config file.')
```

`k` is local to the comprehension; `offending_key` is local to whatever scope contains the comprehension.